# Compilar Web2Py en .exe con CX_Freeze

Tags: python, python-2.7, web2py

Estimados, tengo un problema, quiero convertir la app creada en Web2Py en una app .exe, pero cuando ejecuto cx-freeze me dice este error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 10, in <module>
    from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\__init__.py", line 11, in <modul
e>
    from cx_Freeze.freezer import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 13, in <module
>
    import socket
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: No se encontr¾ el proceso especificado.
```

Creo que es por que estoy tratando de compilar a otro .exe, que es Web2Py, ahora paso el script setup.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Usage:
    Install cx_Freeze: http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/
    Copy script to the web2py directory
    c:\Python27\python standalone_exe_cxfreeze.py build_exe
"""
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
from gluon.import_all import base_modules, contributed_modules
from gluon.fileutils import readlines_file
from glob import glob
import fnmatch
import os
import shutil
import sys
import re

#read web2py version from VERSION file
web2py_version_line = readlines_file('VERSION')[0]
#use regular expression to get just the version number
v_re = re.compile('[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+')
web2py_version = v_re.search(web2py_version_line).group(0)

base = None



if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"

base_modules.remove('macpath')
buildOptions = dict(
    compressed=True,
    excludes=["macpath", "PyQt4"],
    includes=base_modules,
    include_files=[
        'applications',
        'ABOUT',
        'LICENSE',
        'VERSION',
        'logging.example.conf',
        'options_std.py',
        'app.example.yaml',
        'queue.example.yaml',
    ],
    # append any extra module by extending the list below -
    # "contributed_modules+["lxml"]"
    packages=contributed_modules,
)

setup(
    name="Web2py",
    version=web2py_version,
    author="Massimo DiPierro",
    description="web2py web framework",
    license="LGPL v3",
    options=dict(build_exe=buildOptions),
    executables=[Executable("web2py.py",
                            base=base,
                            compress=True,
                            icon="web2py.ico",
                            targetName="web2py.exe",
                            copyDependentFiles=True)],
)
```

No me doy cuenta si existe alguna forma de compilar a binario o convertir en .exe la app creada con web2py.

Answer (score 1):

El problema parece ser que `CX_freeze` no ha podido encontrar la dll `_socket.pyd`, esto podría deberse a varios motivos:

- Algún tema de instalación
- Algún problema producto de mezclar instalaciones de 64 bits / 32 bits

En cualquiera de los casos, probaría reinstalar Python. La otra alternativa "rústica" es configurar el path de búsqueda a la carpeta dónde se encuentre `_socket.pyd`

```
import sys
sys.path.append("Path a _socket.pyd")
import socket
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Patricio Moracho, hice lo que me indicaste y sigo con el mismo problema, reinstale Python 2.7 y también force el path para que encuentre el archivo, pero sigo con el mismo error. import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Python27\web2py_win\web2py\_socket.pyd")
import socket

Comment: Por el error inicial, el problema lo tenés con `_socket.pyd` no con `web2py_win\web2py_socket.pyd`, normalmente esto debería estar en `c:\Python27\DLLs", fijate si eso ayuda

Comment: si si, le coloco la ruta correcta y sigue con el mismo error: import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Python27\DLLs\_socket.pyd')
import socket   ... esto ya me desespera un poco ......... :(

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes la solución y varios ejemplos:
https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/scripts/standalone_exe_cxfreeze.py
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py/cWM0uNildlo

En el grupo de google de web2py tienen una comunidad más activa que resolverá tus dudas mas rápido, saludos.